# Solidity ; not required after enum statement

Tags: solidity, remix

Why is the ; not required after the end of the **enum enuContractStates {Ready, Active, Paused}** statement.  If I add the ; after this statement I get a compile error.

Thank you

```
contract Picard {
    
    string public constant strFullName = "Jean Luc Picard";
    
    enum enuContractStates {Ready, Active, Paused}
    
    enuContractStates public state;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the same reasons as to why it shouldn't be used after functions.

`;` is used to end a statement. A statement is usually introducing a variable or assigning a value to a variable.

However the `{ }` construct is to express a *block*. You shouldn't use semicolon `;` to end a block.